# Not able to start WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0 without logs to analyse

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to run wso2 Enterprise integrator in localhost, It used to run perfectly before. But now I'm facing issue where I'm unable to start it. I couldn't see any errors.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Please could you post your command as text so we can copy it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the terminal logs stop in the windows environment. Please try pressing enter for logs to continue.

If the above solution does not works, please try running the server as a service. [Link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service)